# How to grep undefined values in an array?

Tags: perl

I have an array with an undefined value:

```
[0] 0.1431,
[1] undef
```

I then later push this value onto an array, and Perl doesn't warn me about the uninitialized values (I cannot imagine why someone would want this to happen without a warning or `die`, even when I have `use autodie ':all'` set, but that's another story)

So I try and `grep` on these arrays to prevent pushing `undef` values onto arrays, thus:

```
if (grep {undef} @array) {
    next
}
```

But, this doesn't catch the value.

How can I `grep` for undefined values in Perl5?

Comment: Re "*But, this doesn't catch the value.*", `undef` doesn't check if something is undefined; it makes things undefined and/or returns an undefined scalar (depending on how it's used)

Comment: Re "*even when I have `use autodie ':all'` set*", `push` can't fail, so the concept of making it `die` on failure makes no sense.

Comment: Proper code construction is `next unless defined $var;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` for not defined instead:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (0, undef, undef, 3);

if (grep {! defined} @array) {
    print "undefined values in array\n";
}
```

There are several reasons as to why you'd want to have/allow undefined values in an array. One such beneficial scenario is when passing in positional parameters to a function.

Answer (score 3):

Why not prevent the values from being added in the first place?

Replace

```
push @array, LIST;
```

with

```
push @array, grep defined, LIST;
```

If it's specifically a scalar, you could also use

```
push @array, $scalar if defined($scalar);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [defined](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined) to get rid of undefined items:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my @a1 = (1,2,3,undef,undef,4);
print Dumper(\@a1);

my @a2 = grep { defined } @a1;
print Dumper(\@a2);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          undef,
          undef,
          4
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4
        ];
```